# Injecting properties to spring boot auto-configure classes in a non-spring managed web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee-8

I have created a library to be used as a kafka client using Spring Boot, essentially there are just classes in the library each of which are annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration`
and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class KafkaHandlerConfiguration {
...
}
```

and

```
@Service
interface SwiftalkKafkaGateway {
...
}
```

I create a jar with dependencies for it, and this JAR is to be used in a Java EE webapp via CDI.
I'll get the beans in the CDI context via this code

```
@Singleton
@ApplicationScoped
class SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader {

    private final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext springContext;

    SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader() {
        springContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        springContext.scan("com.digite.cloud.swiftalk");
        springContext.refresh();
    }

    ApplicationContext getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext() {
        return this.springContext;
    }

}
```

How do I pass the properties that the Spring boot auto-configure needs to start the beans? I have both `spring.kafka` group of properties and custom properties that get injected via `@Value` annotations in the `KafkaHandlerConfiguration`

```
@Value("${digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.core-pool-size:10}")
private Integer corePoolSize;

@Value("${digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.max-pool-size:20}")
private Integer maxPoolSize;

@Value("${digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.queue-capacity:100}")
private Integer queueCapacity;
```

and

```
    "spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=1000",
    "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9999",
    "spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer",
```

Comment: Using Spring features without using Spring is not possible.

Comment: Irrelevant comment. It's a different question at play here; to make it simple for you, how to inject properties when creating an `ApplicationContext` programmatically?

Comment: Just creating a context isn't enough for the Spring BOot magic to be available. If it is only value substitution you want/need create a configuration class that includes a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as you would do in a regular Spring application.  However you likely will run into issues trying to bridge CDI and Spring later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ConfigurableEnvironment` and `MutablePropertySource` worked for me; here's how I load the environment into Context

```
@Singleton
@ApplicationScoped
class SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader {

    private final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext springContext;

    SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader() throws IOException {
        springContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        Properties appProps = new Properties();
        appProps.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("spring-config.properties"));
        propertySources.addFirst(new PropertySource<Properties>("spring-properties", appProps) {
            @Override
            public Object getProperty(String name) {
                return appProps.getProperty(name);
            }
        });
        springContext.setEnvironment(environment);
        springContext.scan("com.digite.cloud.swiftalk");
        springContext.refresh();
    }

    ApplicationContext getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext() {
        return this.springContext;
    }

}
```

added a file in `src/test/resources`

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=embedded
spring.data.mongodb.port=12345
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=2000
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:19092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
digite.swiftalk.kafka.upstream-type-header=UPSTREAM-TYPE
digite.swiftalk.kafka.upstream-instance-header=INSTANCE-HEADER
digite.swiftalk.kafka.message-key-header=MESSAGE-KEY-HEADER
digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.core-pool-size=20
digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.max-pool-size=50
digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.queue-capacity=1000
```

And the test

```
@Test
void testLoadsSpringApplicationContext() throws IOException {
    SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader loader = new SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader();
    SwiftalkKafkaGateway kafkaGateway = loader.getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext().getBean(SwiftalkKafkaGateway.class);
    assertNotNull(kafkaGateway);

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor asyncExecutor = loader.getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext().getBean(
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
    Assertions.assertTrue(asyncExecutor.getCorePoolSize() == 20);
}
```

The default value for `corePoolSize` is 10 in the spring boot library

```
@Value("${digite.swiftalk.kafka.executor.core-pool-size:10}")
private Integer corePoolSize;
```